# combination gre problem # 24

Tags: combinatorics, gre-exam

How many ways can 4 prizes be given away to 3 boys, if each boy is eligible for all the prizes?

Can anyone explain me why this answer is wrong: 4*4*4 ?

Comment: $4\times4\times4$ would be the number of ways of giving three distinct prizes to four boys.  Four ways to distribute the first prize, four ways to distribute the second prize, four ways to distribute the third prize.

Comment: are the presents different, or are they all the same, can it be all the presents go to only one kid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let 4 prizes, $p_1, p_2, p_3, p_4$ and 3 boys, $b_1, b_2, b_3$

Each price $p_i$ has a choose $c_i$ of a boy. So

$c_1 \in \{b_1, b_2, b_3\}$ 
$c_2 \in \{b_1, b_2, b_3\}$ 
$c_3 \in \{b_1, b_2, b_3\}$ 
$c_4 \in \{b_1, b_2, b_3\}$

And set of the options is $\{b_1, b_2, b_3\} \times \{b_1, b_2, b_3\}
\times \{b_1, b_2, b_3\} \times \{b_1, b_2, b_3\}$,
and the size of the set is $|\{b_1, b_2, b_3\}|^4 = 3^4$.

Answer (score 1):

You only have one of each prize, so it is true that you have $4$ possibilities for the first boy. For the second boy, you only have $3$ prizes left, since you have already given $1$ away. Likewise, there are $2$ possibilities for the third boy, giving you a total of $4\cdot 3\cdot 2=24$.

EDIT: I assume you have to give each boy a prize. If each of the $4$ prizes are given randomly (such that a boy might win more than one), you would have $3^4$ different ways.

Comment: The assumption that each boy must be given a prize yields an answer not equal to $3^4$. There is no need to give each boy a prize. The only way to obtain $3^4$ possibilities is to include cases where one or two boys get no prize. What is a valid assumption is that each prize must be awarded.

Comment: @amWhy: No, that was not what I meant. In my original answer I assumed that each boy would receive a prize. Then after re-reading the question I realized that this assumption might be wrong. Therefore, I clarified my assumptions and gave an alternative answer if a different assumption was made (where all prizes are awarded and one or two boys may receive no prize). I'm sorry if that was unclear.

Answer (score 1):

Since each boy is eligible for all the prizes;there are 3 possibilities for each prize, giving us 3^4=81 possibilities.